# How do I control my DVD using the Xbox in order to watch a movie?

Tags: xbox

How do I control my DVD using the Xbox to watch a movie?  Do I use the joystick or voice commands or something else?

Comment: Is this an Xbox 360 or original Xbox?

Answer (score 7):

For the original Xbox you need a remote control. This comes with a dongle that fits into one of the controller ports.

For the Xbox 360 you use one of the controllers. The thumbsticks control movement between the options and you use "A" to select.

Comment: The extra beauty of the remote and dongle for the original Xbox was that once you bought it, the controller suddenly also worked. Weasle marketing at it's best!